# How do I do a jasmine unit test for my angular directive that needs to test its emit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

How do I do a jasmine unit test for my angular directive that needs to test its emit?

This directive is a attribute directive and has an emit inside the directive that I need to test.

hows best to do this?

This is my current test:

```
   //broadcast test:
     describe('broadcast called', function() {

           var rootScope, testService;

           beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, $injector) {              
                rootScope = _$rootScope_;

                testService = $injector.get('testFactory');

                spyOn(rootScope, "broadcast");
           })); 

           it('should be broadcast', function() {
              testService.emitTest();
              expect(rootScope.broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test1');
           });
    });
```

Current code:

```
appservicemod.factory('testFactory', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

        var emitTest = function(){  

                    $rootScope.$broadcast('test1');

        }   

        return {
            emitTest: emitTest
        } 
    }
]);
```

Comment: Spy on the scope `emit` method and verify that it is called when you expect it to be called with the expected arguments

Comment: What does `testService.emitTest` do? Can't tell what's wrong without knowing this.

Comment: thats the name of the function that has a broadcast inside it. I will add that above aswell

Comment: I've added my factory above for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your current approach works fine, except for a few issues:

- it should be `$broadcast`, not `broadcast` everywhere
- there's no `beforeEach(module('app'))` in your code

If you fix these issues, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/MMiszy/c4fz58sp/1/

```
describe('broadcast called', function() {
   var $rootScope, testService;

   beforeEach(module('app'));

   beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, $injector) {              
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        spyOn($rootScope, "$broadcast");
        testService = $injector.get('testFactory');
   })); 

   it('should broadcast', function() {
      testService.emitTest();
      expect($rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test1');
   });
});
```

Comment: what would the expect be?

Comment: I just want to check if the broadcast fired? in your above example I can change test1 to test100 and that still passes, so doesnt seem like a valid test

Comment: I want to spyOn the broadcast basically

Comment: There's no expect. It's an async test, it waits until the `done` function gets called.

Comment: But I could do this and it still works: rootScope.$on('yoyo', done);

Comment: Do you broadcast event named `yoyo` anywhere? If so, then it succeeds obviously. If not, it fails.

Comment: I have nothing called yoyo and it passes

Comment: You're not using Jasmine 2.0 then. See my updated answer.

Comment: I get an error still: called "Expected a spy but got undefined"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107133/discussion-between-miszy-and-angularm).

Answer (score 1):

spy

```
spyOn(scope, 'emit');
```

and in the test verify it was called

```
expect(scope.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('valueItShouldBeCalledWith');
```

Comment: How would I do the same but in a factory?

Comment: With regards to watching for a scope.emit call there's no difference

Comment: I've added my current broadcast example above. But cant get it working

Comment: First of all, it's `$emit` not `emit`. Moreover, the OP is not using `$emit`, but rather `$broadcast` in his code so this wouldn't work even if there was no typo. Lastly, there's no `$scope` (and certainly not `scope`) inside of factories and services so this code doesn't make sense. Did you mean `$rootScope`?